# appcompat_v7 Error in Eclipse(Android)

Tags: android, eclipse

i'm new in android development . i installed Eclipse and JDK and  Installed( API 20) and (API 8) and all the extras but when i opened eclipse for android project i got error in Appcompat_v7(res->values_v23->styles_base.xml->( 
)  .

Error is :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGmwT.png)
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.   styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v23

Comment: @harshadpansuriya its eclipse :)

Comment: I second what Maheshwar Ligade said. If you're just starting with Android development, use Android Studio instead of Eclipse. The Eclipse plugin is not supported anymore by Google so you're likely to get more and more errors in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **Compile Sdk to 23**. That Solve my Problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

As the OP has now Android Studio,

here are a few links to tackle the same,,

[Boost up Gradle build time - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips/17286002#17286002)

[Boost up Gradle build time - 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/android-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build)

basically you need to add `org.gradle.daemon=true` to `build.gradle` file.

you can search for similar, and will find many threads on SO for the same,

**Note: Its not "Guaranteed" to work but why not give a try**

I would suggest you to use `Android Studio` instead of `Eclipse`.

Now the error, you will have to update your `SDK platform` to `API 23` which is the Latest API(as of now), as it will require that particular version for compiling. Your current is API 20 which will not include the `styles` which is required by `appcompat_v7`.

Comment: i have 3gb RAM installed in my system. i installed Android studio but it hanged my system again and again. so i installed eclipse. thank you brother for your suggestion. i'm going to install API 23.

Comment: Great to update :), does it hang when you build the App ? Means the gradle system continuously runs and does not build the project ?

Comment: when i open android studio it hang my system. i have installed new windows and then install  android studio again  but hang . so i choose eclipse.

Comment: Its a problem with many and there's nothing we can do other than upgrading system, and yes if `AndroidStudio` run someday and the build system takes time than you can do a few changes with the `build.gradle` file that will somehow boost up the build time, and yes instead of windows try `Android Studio` in `Ubuntu`. Happy coding :)

Comment: i again installed Android Studio. but this time its working fine. i installed Geny motion and configure it with Android studio. but when i run the project it takes too much time. " gradle build  running ". kindly guide me how to increase its  performance. thanks