# Android Studio Gradle build keeps on running for more than half an hour

Tags: android, android-studio

This week i reinstalled my OS(Ubuntu 14.04 amd64),in the new OS(same Ubuntu) i copied installed the backup of android 2.0 and the sdk, now the gradle build is running for more than half an hour

Comment: Restart IDE once and check it again.

Comment: It is recommended that you reinstall Android Studio, however you can still use the same sdk, provided you give the same path for sdk.

Comment: Check the proxy settings, give this a try.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/android-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build

Comment: Try searching for similar questions before posting. It creates duplicates and difficult for people to get genuine answers.

Comment: Invalidate cache and restart. @abishek.

Answer (score 0):

Click File then Goto Settings ->Build Execution and Deployment ->Build tools -> Gradle , there you will find one check box offline work , check that check box .
It may help building faster .

Answer (score 0):

try increasing the memory allocation of Android studio by updating VMoptions file.

you get decrease your gradle file build duration by following the link below.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Everyone. I solved the problem by   restarting android studio and then giving execute permission to, **"aapt","dx","zipalign"** files in my */sdk/23.0.2/build-tools*  and   **"adb"** file in */sdk/platform-tools*