# Stuck with Gradle Build Running

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

While trying to build my Application on Android Studio 2.1 (On Ubuntu 16.04), it gets stuck on the below note:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
```

Can anybody please help me out.

Comment: while my problem wasn't exactly the same (i had an endless "Starting gradle daemon..." loop), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64844390/3438172) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Actually it is not stuck. It takes more time to build. I have got almost 3 solutions that can fix the issue.

### Solution-1:

Following the steps will make it 10 times faster and reduce build time 90%

First create a file named `gradle.properties` in the following directory:

```
/home/<username>/.gradle/ (Linux)
/Users/<username>/.gradle/ (Mac)
C:\Users\<username>\.gradle (Windows)
```

Add this line to the file:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true

org.gradle.parallel=true
```

---

### Solution-2:

If Android Studio has a proxy server setting and can't reach the server then it takes a long time to build, probably its trying to reach the proxy server and waiting for a timeout. When I removed the proxy server setting its working fine.

In Android Studio go to `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle`

Check the `'Offline work'` under `'Global Gradle settings'`

It will reduce 90% gradle build time.

---

### Solution-3

If you are using Google Play services, make sure you aren't using this in your Gradle build script:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

Only use those Google APIs that your app is really using. If all you are using is Google Maps, you would use this:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0
```

When I did this, my compile time went from over 2 minutes to around 25 seconds. For a list of the Google apis that you can selectively compile against, see:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

### Resource Link:

1. [Android Studio gradle takes too long to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/android-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build)
2. [Discussion about stuck in gradle build](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RicardoAmaral/posts/e9PG6vSN5w3)

### Solution#4:

[Arun George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6189004/arun-george) has commented the following solution.

> the issue was due to certain 32 bit libraries missing. Had to do `sudo apt-get install lib32z1`. Adding to gradle.properties helped reduce
> the build time.

Comment: I think, the issue was due to certain 32 bit libraries missing. Had to do `sudo apt-get install lib32z1`. Adding to gradle.properties helped reduce the build time. Thanks:)

Comment: org.gradle.parallel=true should be used only with decoupled projects (IE: project that don't share objects). You can read more here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects

Comment: i have same probelm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502164/android-studio-2-2-3-gradle-build-running-stuck

Comment: Solution 1 makes builds finish 20 times faster for me!

Comment: In Solution-1 is this a text file that you save as "gradle.properties"?

Answer (score 7):

Changing `buildToolsVersion` was the solution for me.

Comment: This is the real solution.  And sometimes the problem isn't caught by the warnings we so often see in the build.gradle file.  Thanks!

Comment: Elaborating: click the Project tab (upper-left corner)> right-click the "app" folder> click "Open Module Settings" > Modules > Properties > Select a version for "Compile SDK Version" and a version for "Build Tools Version" . 
Source: https://www.py4u.net/discuss/646549 
Anyone tried selecting a version only for "Build Tools Version"?

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that the project isn't synced with the gradle files. The resolution I did was go to `File > Sync Project with Gradle Files` and it was able to sync.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried all solution. Nothing has worked. So I just restarted my PC and its working fine. You can try it.

Answer (score 3):

For my case I had to install `gcc-multilib`

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

Check the Gradle Console at the bottom right as it has more output than the Event log.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably behind the proxy, you might have recently changed your password or something has changed. Go to

```
/home/<username>/.gradle/ (Linux)
/Users/<username>/.gradle/ (Mac)
C:\Users\<username>\.gradle (Windows)
```

in gradle.properties file, delete/ change proxy settings. They are different to your android studio proxy settings.

Had the same issue, gradle used to take an hour to build. After I deleted proxy settings from gragle.properties file, it now takes couple seconds.

Comment: This worked for me. It turns out that even though I set the proxy to No Proxy in Android Studio, the gradle.proerties  file still contains Proxy entries.

Comment: I can't find gradle.properties. Is it supposed to be in the .gradle folder, inside any subfolder or do I have to create it? If I have to create it, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding more to @SkyWalker's answer:

Also check if you have the latest version of gradle. Updating [gradle plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio) to the latest version could help.

Note: I have a similar setup(Android Studio 2.1 on Ubuntu 16.04), and I had a similar problem. Updating gradle to the latest version solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolution for Gradle stuck using Android Studio version 4.2.2:**

When the resources are downloaded successfully the Android Studio should be restarted with "Invalidate cache and restart" and offline Gradle mode should be activated before platform-tools indexing.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's bad way, but start studio with
sudo nice --17 *IDE name*
seems worked for me