# android studio is stuck at refreshing gradle project

Tags: android, performance, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, performance-testing

I updated my android studio few days ago to version 2.1 and now whenever I open a project in it or import a project it says in the bottom refreshing 'project name' gradle project I waited four hours for it to refresh but it not moving further help me out with this because i need my android studio normal any help would be much appreciated thank you in advance.
[image: Here is the image of my problem]

Comment: perhaps, you need to check for updates again, maybe it was a partial update

Comment: i updated it completely it was not partial.

Comment: now when i check for new updates it tells me you already have the latest version of android studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting the `.gradle` directory from your home folder and the project folder and rebuild the project.

Comment: do i have to delete .gradle folder from every project i want to open because when i delete from a project then only it works

Comment: when i delete the gradle folder from home directory and project directory and build it again it says gradle project sync failed

Comment: please someone help me here what is the problem i am getting again and again

Comment: Are you sure everything is up-to-date? Update the sdk build tool and update the `buildToolsVersion` in gradle.build with the same. And update the `classpath` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0` in gradle.build(project level). Then go to `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` Tell me if the problem persists

Comment: everything was updated i only updated gradle and it's fine now thank you. 
but whenever i import the project the problem still persisits why is it so?

Comment: Maybe its taking to much time to build. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37063659/2686502)

Comment: thank you i have sent you request in skype please add me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502164/android-studio-2-2-3-gradle-build-running-stuck

Answer (score 3):

I experienced a similar problem after updating my android studio and fixed it by pressing ctr+alt+s then selecting the gradle tab and fixing the location of my local gradle distribution. somehow after the update the location changed from the correct

"D:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-2.14.1" 
to

"D:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle"

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting all the .lock & .lck Files from .gradle directory from your home folder
and rebuild

### steps

1. search for .lock files in  C:\Users{USER}.gradle
2. select and delete them all
3. search for .lck files in  C:\Users{USER}.gradle
4. select and delete them all

Answer (score 0):

When open your project do not click on error messages "fix plugin and refresh project" it will led you infinite waiting. Instead go to build.gradle file and change plugin version to your current version and then Sync project.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because downloading the new version gradle costing too much time. It is wating for the downloading, so studio stucks.

If you don't want to wait, just modify the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file(It's path is `YOUR_PROJECT/gradle/wrapper/`) to your previous version, e.g.

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`

and restart the studio.