# Android Studio 2.2.3 Gradle Build Running Stuck

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I download android studio 2.2.3 and load my project. But Gradle Build Running Stuck. It continuously shows that and i am not able to run my app. what is the issue can any one help me with that?

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
```

[image]

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: 8 minutes is not that much to be honest :)

Comment: yeah but i waited more than 21 minutes also

Comment: You can click on the progress bar to see what process is running.

Comment: Are you behind a Proxy ? If yes, did you configure Android Studio for it ?

Comment: yes i am behind proxy

Comment: Ok check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are behind a proxy, create a `gradle.properties` file next to your `build.gradle` file with this :

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=YOUR_PROXY
systemProp.http.proxyPort=YOUR_PORT
systemProp.http.proxyUser=USERNAME
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=PASSWORD

systemProp.https.proxyHost=YOUR_PROXY
systemProp.https.proxyPort=YOUR_PORT
systemProp.https.proxyUser=USERNAME
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=PASSWORD
```

`systemProp.http[s].proxyUser` and `systemProp.http[s].proxyPassword` are not required if you don't need to login for your proxy. In such a case, remove these lines.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a internet connection.
If you have it , so maybe android studio couldn't download classes from `Jcenter`. So you have to force android studio to download classes from other resource like `Maven`.

To do that open `gradle.build` file and change the two `jcenter()` text with `mavenCentral()` ("C" in maven"C"entral() must be typed in uppercase) and try syncing with gradle again.

You don't need to do that every time you open your project. Just do this every time you create a new project in Android studio.

Comment: yeah i have internet connection

Comment: so your answer is in the rest of the text

Comment: change that `gradle.build` file to this:buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: yeah i did mavenCentral() but not able to click on syncnow

Comment: why ? what happen?

Comment: just because gradle build running

Comment: simply close android studio and open it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132471/discussion-between-aditya-vyas-lakhan-and-amirhosein).

Answer (score 0):

Solutions: 
 1. update your Build tools.
 2. Reinstall sdk.

In my case, all the executable ".exe" files in "sdk\build-tools\25.0.3" folder were corrupted by virus. solution 2 worked for my perfectly. :)