# Android Studio stuck on gradle build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

All was working fine until I upgraded Android Studio to version 2.2. Now, when I start a new project or open an existing project, Android Studio is stuck with "**Building 'MyApp' Gradle project Info**". It would be of great help if someone can help me with this. [Screenshot of the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynUQn.jpg)

Things that I have tried so far,

1. Let it run. It did not help.
2. Deleted the .gradle folder at C:\Users\.gradle2
3. Manually downloading gradle and placing the files at C:\Users\.gradle\wrapper\dists\
4. Completely uninstallting Android studio and reinstalling the same new version.

Comment: How is your Internet connectivity? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes. It is fine. I should also mention that Android studio is working fine in my other computer which is running version 1.5.1

Comment: Can you make sure that Android Studio is not downloading something? Try checking Network/Activity Monitor on *nix or Task Manager on Windows.

Comment: @Sufian I'm on windows and I could see some network activity when it (And Studio) is running. But, is there an way I can check what it is trying to download ? Is there a log being written by Android Studio or Gradle ?

Comment: Probably some of the imports you've added in your `build.gradle`

Comment: Take a look into [solutions here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063217/stuck-with-gradle-build-running).

Comment: delete project/.gradle folder

Comment: Nothing worked. I had to go back to the old version of android studio. I'm sure I should be missing something but could not afford to wait and work out the new version.