# Android Studio 2.3 stuck at building project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I updated android studio to 2.3 and it stuck at building project then I removed it and downloaded a new one. Then while trying to import a project, it is now stuck at this. Please provide me some possible solutions to this problem.
[image]

Comment: Can you access the menu? If yes, try to invalidate the cache and restart

Comment: No, can't access the menu

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063217/stuck-with-gradle-build-running) it will help you out.

Comment: Wait a little bit if it is the first time you create a project in the newest version...android might be downloading files to wrapper in the gradle

Answer (score 0):

Lots of 2.3 problems this week.

Try this:

• Close Android Studio

• Go to the directory home_dir/.AndroidStudio/system/cache

• Remove all the files in the cache directory.

• Then restart IntelliJ / Android Studio

I'd suggest making a backup of anything before removing. Also remember to export settings before deleting cache.

Comment: do you know the location of this folder be on a mac

Comment: @theanilpaudel (make sure that Finder shows hidden files and folders), then try searching in **_HddName_ > Users > _YourUserName_** and also in the subfolder of **_YourUserName_ > Library > Android**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Clearing cache did not solve it.

First, install the latest updates for build tools and emulator.

Then wait for few minutes while building the project as it might have been downloading some files in the background.

After a few minutes, everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Gradle wrapper have been downloaded especially behind a proxy.

~/.gradle/wrapper/dist/*