# Gradle Build Error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I just started using Android Studio and I was trying to run my app until Gradle build error popped out:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
```

Please help!
thanks

Comment: Post the code of the gradle and the complete log

Comment: Going to have to post the full output / error message if you expect any kind of solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the gradle console at the botton right as it has more output than the Event log.

Maybe the problem is that you just have to update gradle to the last version, and it should solve the problem.

If it does not work, take a look at that answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063217/stuck-with-gradle-build-running)

Hope it helps you!
vote answer if it does!

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: sorry but I can't comment upside because i don't have 50 reputation yet! :(