# 40 tasks of OpenJDK Platform Binary continues running in background after closing android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android Studio opens almost 35 to 40 OpenJDK Platform Binary which hangs my pc. But even after closing, all the tabs remain running.
Android Studio Version: Arctic Fox| 2020.3.1 Patch 1

When Android Studio is running
[image]

When Android Studio is closed
[image]

Comment: Which version of android studio you are using ? Update your question with those details

Comment: @AgentP version is Android Studio Arctic Fox| 2020.3.1 Patch 1. I have updated the question.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64844390/3438172) out, see if it helps