# Android studio 3.1.4 stuck on gradle build running

Tags: android, gradle, build

I'm working on Android Studio 3.1.4, gradle 4.4.
It was fine but suddenly it get stuck in "gradle build running."
There is no error messsage.
I copy the project folder to another machine and it build fast and fine.
I need to build it in my machine.
I have uninstalled e installed the gradle and studio some times and it continue get stuck on build.
Any ideas?

print screen of build messages in my machine
[image]

print screen of success build in another machine

[image]

```
Gradle Project
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1252'

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.savetyre"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
Gradle app
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: What are your system specs, and how much RAM are you giving to Android Studio?

Comment: show your build.gradle file of both App and Project and gradle.properties also.

Comment: Included glade.properties in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As long you moved your project to new device i think no problem as stuck its working on 
download gradle dist, take some time normally 5-15 mins depends upon internet connection speed.

You can use some tricks to make it faster:-

1. Goto C:\Users[USERNAME].gradle\wrapper\dists.
2. Download appropriate gradle version as [4.4-all](http://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip).
3. Delete gradle-4.4-all.zip.lck and other files from directory..
4. Paste the new downloaded gradle-4.4-all.zip here.
5. Run the android studio agein.

Answer (score 0):

Because downloading Gradle takes a lot of time when your network situation is not so good, you have to download it by yourself.
My solution is:

1. **Download a new version of gradle**, such as gradle-4.3-all.zip, etc., and put the file in your AS Gradle location (Mac: go to the Application folder and open the package of AS, and put the new gradle in the Gradle folder. PS: If your new gradle version folder is not found, then you can create it on your own.Windows: like the previous two answers);
2. **Disconnect your Wifi or LAN;**
3. Open Android Studio 3.0 as usual;
4. **DO NOT OPEN YOUR PROJECT IMMEDIATELY, TURN TO THE PREFERENCE PART FIRST;**
5. **GO TO THE GRADLE PART, DO THE SETTINGS AND SWITCH THE OFFLINE MODE ON;**
6. Open the project you want to open;
7. Let AS to index the file and modify the gradle.properties when it is still indexing.
8. **Turn on you Wifi or LAN**, and AS will download the missing file. **ATTENTION:** **DO NOT MODIFY YOUR ANDROID MANIFEST OR OTHER FILES WHEN DOWNLOADING**
9. **Close AS and reopen the project.** And everything will be fine. :-)

If you still stuck at "Building Gradle Project", just redo all of these. Still not clear? Comment below.

Comment: I had done it already. And I have a fast internet connection. The build is not slow, it's stucked. It is happening in my machine, I copied the project to another machine and the build worked fine and fast. thank you.

Comment: you can try first post from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063217/stuck-with-gradle-build-running

Comment: I had tried and still got stuck. I don't understand how it can run in one machine and not in another in the same company with the same configurations and internet speed.

Comment: have u tried the solutions that i have posted in comment

Comment: Then try reinstalling android studio

Comment: I have reinstalled android studio , gradle build off-line mode, download gradle 4.4 all, several times before open this question.

Comment: @JulioCarvalho do you have teamviewer?

Comment: Yes I have. But I can't share it with you because my company directives

Comment: ohk no problem @JulioCarvalho