# Project opening time is too much in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

If I make an Android project using Android Studio which is **already created** in my computer and then I close this project and again open this project it takes only 5 to 10 seconds to open in Android Studio.

But when I try to open some external Android project in Android Studio which is not created by the Android Studio takes too much time to open in Android Studio. Each time Android Studio shows only this screen for long time.

I use **Android Studio 2.1.3**

[image: Android Studio Opening]

Comment: This is because Android Studio is downloading the SDK dependencies. So it'll take time based on your internet speed. Once the android project is setup, it'll open up normally again.

Comment: there haven't any options to cancel project when this screen appears.

Answer (score 0):

It is downloading the dependencies. Make sure you have a proper internet connection for gradle to download the dependeicies. If you are behind a proxy server configure the proxy in `gradle.properties` file before opening the project.

Configure proxy server as follows inside `gradle.properties` file:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=10.27.11.34
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=10.27.11.34
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
```

Comment: How to configure proxy in gradle.settings file?

Comment: Please put another question regarding this.

Comment: I am new to android development so i didn't get it where i put this code in which gradle.properties file. Should i put into Projectname->gradle->wrapper->gradle-wrapper.properties? @AndroidMechanic

Comment: no, it should be in the project folder directly. if there is none, create one and put your proxy server details in it as seen in the answer.

Comment: not working again it takes too much time @AndroidMechanic

Comment: did you change the proxy server to yours?

Comment: I don't know how to do it can you please provide me details? @AndroidMechanic

Answer (score 0):

Here are some useful recommendations to speed up the Android Studio in terms of its gradle build time, memory usage although in your case it seems that Android Studio is taking time to download dependencies, creating supported directory structure & build the Project.

There could be proxy settings enable in Android Studio that you might need to disable

Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/android-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build) to figure out your issue

Comment: i don't have enable any proxy settings.No proxy option is already checked in my android studio @Farhan

Comment: Ok did you applied the suggested changes mentioned in the link & are these effective to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

i deleted all gradle folder and copied it from another project and pasted it, this worked for me