# Not able to update the multidex behavior

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, build.gradle, android-multidex

My application was working fine but that problem came which is related to multidex android. I searched for the problem and did the essential update according to android.developers guide. But its been hours i am fighting with the same problem. Applied different solutions but still the same issue is there. One gradle build is taking 11-12 minutes straight away and to test a solution i have to wait 11-12 minutes which is really killing me. I am sharing my Gradle and manifest file. Please help regarding this issue.

Build.Gradle File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mudasir.login"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude'META-INF/license.txt'

    }
    dexOptions{
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'

}
```

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mudasir.login">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_screen_activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignInActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_signin_"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".sidemenu_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">


        </activity>

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add following dependency in your gradle file

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

For more information, visit : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: let me check.. this is the only problem..??

Comment: Yes, you have already specified multidexEnabled true and updated application tag

Comment: ok let me try.. It will take 10 miuntes gradle build to check one solution..:(

Comment: It was also showing that UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL Error on gradle build. It was also due to that missing dependency..??

Comment: Yeah buddy it was all due to that missing dependency. I applied the solution from the same link but in hurry skipped that dependency. Thanks a lot for you quick help.

Comment: Can you tell why it took so long in gradle build. Its the separate problem for me...

Comment: dont use whole google-play service, instead use only those libraries which you want to use.
like compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0', if you only want to use gcm service. This will definately save some build time. Also check this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/android-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup
Table 1. Individual APIs and corresponding build.gradle descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this part to your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

But the **real issue** is that you are using:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

You **shouldn't ever be using** `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'` as that includes every Google Play services library - only use the [APIs you need](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split).

The same for the **v4 Support Library** that has been split into several [smaller modules.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#24-2-0-v4-refactor)