# Why when my app starts it take long time(7-10 sec) ?? Android,Java

Tags: java, android, background-process

I am building android app that get Installed apps using PackageManager and files (Not all file just the files ends with(txt,docx,MP4,3gp,wmv,mp3,apk) from the device when it starts (i do that inside onStart() function),

actually in the first version take about 12-15 sec But i do some process using AsyncTask in Background and that help me a little, But still not enough for me >>
I need to run the app without delay !!! or if there some tricks to do what i want ??

the Code :

```
public class GetApps {


private PackageManager packageManager = null;
private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
MainActivity activity;

public GetApps( MainActivity act,PackageManager pm) {

    this.activity=act;
    this.packageManager = pm;
    new LoadApplications().execute();
}


private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {

    ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> appList = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        ApplicationInfo info = list.get(i);
        try {
            if (packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName) != null) {
                appList.add(info);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return appList;
}

private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<ApplicationInfo>> {

    private ProgressDialog progress = null;

    @Override
    protected List<ApplicationInfo> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        super.onPostExecute(list);
        MainActivity.progressDialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println(">>>>8 onPostExecute ...");
        activity.callBackDataFromAsynctask(list);// To MainActivit Clas
    }


}
```

and in the main activity i fill three arrays (name and package name and icons)

the Code:

```
public void callBackDataFromAsynctask(final List<ApplicationInfo> list) {

    System.out.println(">>>>9 callBackDataFromAsynctask ...");

    values = new String[list.size()+namesOfFiles.size()];
    values1 = new String[list.size()+namesOfFiles.size()];
    icons1 = new Drawable[list.size()+namesOfFiles.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        ApplicationInfo Info = list.get(i);
        try {
            values[i] = Info.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
            values1[i] = Info.packageName;
            try {
                icons1[i] = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(values1[i]);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



            insertNamesOfFiles(list.size());

    System.out.println(">>>>10 Complete ...");



}
```

and this code the get files names

```
public void insertNamesOfFiles(int iii)
{
     int j = 0;
    for ( int i =iii; i < values.length; i++) {
        values[i] = namesOfFiles.get(j);
        values1[i]="gogo";

        if (values[i].endsWith(".txt"))
            icons1[i] = txt;
        else if (values[i].endsWith(".docx"))
            icons1[i] = doc;
        else if (values[i].endsWith(".MP4") || values[i].endsWith(".3gp"))
            icons1[i] = vid;
        else if (values[i].endsWith(".wmv") || values[i].endsWith(".mp3"))
            icons1[i] = adu;
        else if (values[i].endsWith(".apk"))
            icons1[i] = apk;

        j++;

    }
}
```

Thx in Advance

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/android-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build

Comment: @javadaskari thx for reply ,, but my problem with the process that happening in the first run (get apps and files and fill them in 3 arrays)

Comment: @javadaskari  to be ensure i deleted the lines that responsible for that process and the app run fast and normal !!