# Android Gradle build taking Too much time

Tags: gradle

I am newbie to programming & my Android studio 2.2.1  is taking too much time for build process (nearly 15 Min) and it is not a duplicate question. I have followed the the link [Android Studio gradle takes too long to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/androi-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build) ,but unable to fix the issue. &  My RAM size is of 4GB.

Please guide me

Comment: Do you expect us to enumerate all things that can lead to a slow build? Your program is too large, your machine is too slow, your network connection is too slow, ...

Comment: Sir, Machine is speed for all other development tools, my project's apk file is of 10MB  & my network connections is faster.

Comment: Glad to meet you sir

Comment: something this problem occur due to version mismatch of dependent jar in your.