# Open project Libgdx by Androidstudio 2.2.3

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

`Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)` - i import project from this option and it works on my notebook, but when i try to import this same project in computer (with from same option), i see only `build gradle` in infinity.

It is horrible, i try to open project form 2 days and i no have idea now. 
Maybe i should install something to `android studio` ?

Like this:

[image: Screenshot]

EDIT: This is not a duplicate question. My problem is not "Too long"; my problem is "Never opened".

Comment: first time it takes time because it downloads all the artifact that are required by your libgdx project. Internet speed may be the reason.

Comment: android studio always show that something needs to download

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio gradle takes too long to build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/android-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

In Android Studio go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Check the 'Offline work' under 'Global Gradle settings'

It will make the gradle build 90% faster.

Comment: maybe it is faster, but i cant go to setting before project will be opened

Comment: Press Ctrl+Alt+S for setting from HomeScreen of Android Studio

Comment: @rambo200000 what's the current status