# Android Studio 2.3.1 - editing build.gradle file causes IDE to freeze for 20 seconds (or more)

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-studio-2.3

The past few days, I've experienced some unusual problems in Android Studio 2.3.1; the IDE freezes whenever I edit the build.gradle (module) file.

- My Project-level gradle settings are Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)
- `gradle-wrapper.properties` is as follows:

  ```
  distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
  distributionPath=wrapper/dists
  zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
  zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
  ```
- My local Gradle version (defined by GRADLE_USER_HOME) is Gradle 3.5
- Android Studio does not have a proxy server setting enabled as described in this post [Android Studio gradle takes too long to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/android-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build)
- my `gradle.properties` file is as follows

  ```
  org.gradle.daemon=true
  org.gradle.parallel=true
  ```
- my `build.gradle` file is as follows

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
      compileSdkVersion 25
      buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
      defaultConfig {
          applicationId "app.com.eventfull.waterjam"
          minSdkVersion 16
          targetSdkVersion 25
          versionCode 1
          versionName "1.0"
          testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      }
      buildTypes {
          release {
              minifyEnabled false
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          }
      }

      dataBinding.enabled=true
  }

  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',         {
          exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
      })

      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

      compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
      compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.0'
      compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'

      compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
      compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  }

  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
  ```

I tried toggling the **offline work** option in **Global Gradle Settings** (Settings > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle), but this has no effect; IDE still hangs up when editing the `build.gradle` file.  Thoughts?

---

EDITS:

Here are my custom VM OPTIONS.

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx2g
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

A complete un-install & re-install seems to have fixed this issue.
I dislike resorting to such measures - I'd rather know the *why* - but it was nonetheless effective.

---

**UPDATES on 6.25.2017**

Despite uninstalling & reinstalling Android Studio, Gradle, rebooting my system, cleaning various system caches a few times...Android Studio still freezes for 
~30s to 60secs upon editing a gradle file. I've taken to editing the gradle files in an external text editor & Sync Project with Gradle Files. It helps, but Android Studio *still* seems to freeze intermittently for ~20secs or longer after doing this. Toggling the "offline mode" in gradle settings does nothing.

I'm using...

- Android Studio 2.3.3 (for production apps)
- Android Studio 3.0 canary 4 (for experimenting & ideas).
- 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' is the gradle android build tools in Android 2.3.3
- Macbook Pro (Mid 2015), Core-i7, 16GB RAM, Sierra 10.12.5

Let me know if someone has any suggestions...

---

**UPDATE 4/02/2018**

The problem has disappeared since Google added a special repository for Android Studio users, that is, the **embedded Maven repository** for Android Studio 3+.

Android Studio 2.3.3 and lower doesn't have this.

INSTRUCTIONS

1. Open Android Studio's Preferences - ⌘, (mac) or CTRL ALT S (win)
2. search for 'embedded'
3. click **Enable embedded Maven repository**

[image: embedded maven repository]

Comment: For me the freeze lasts about a minute and then it unfreezes.  Edit a little more and it freezes again for about a minute.  Was that your experience?

Comment: yup. successive edits (either back-to-back or not) still cause Android Studio to freeze for ~ a minute. It's not a one-time thing.  Moreover, all my edits are rather minor; I'm not appending/editing huge amts of info in the gradle files.

See my edits above for things I've tried since I posted about this problem. I plan to ask a guru about this at AnDevCon later in July.

Comment: You can have a try : when you editing your `build.gradle`, turn off the computer network.

Comment: I also have the problem.  Mac sierra system.  Do you solve it?

Comment: When I edit this file android studio will send request to search.maven.org then frozen. So I add 127.0.0.1 search.maven.org to hosts then restart android studio it will not frozen again, but sometimes we need visit search.maven.org too.

Comment: Same here. Any update?

Comment: @sebasira Same here too :(

Comment: I've got the exact same issue on Ubuntu 17.10, Android Studio 3.1.1 and I tried all the suggested solutions, including yours, but I still have this annoying problem.

Comment: I'm working on a Mac & Windows, and ever since the 'embedded maven repository' option in Android Studio, the freezing/slowness hasn't been a problem.  I'll try it out on Ubuntu in a few days & report back.

Comment: That'd be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I've got the same issue on Windows 10, suggested solution didn't work. :(

Comment: Good news. Last night I got notified of Android Studio 3.1.2 update and after update, the problem was solved. After a day of using it, I don't see the issue anymore. :)