# How to get Android Studio to automatically update the Android Gradle Plugin & Gradle to the current version

Tags: android-studio, gradle, gradle-plugin

## **Question:**

Is there *any* way to have **Android Studio** ***automatically* update** Gradle Plugin & Gradle to the latest versions && then immediately **sync the project with the gradle files**?

### **Background:**

I've been working with native Android for over 18 months, and I frequently reference old projects.  When I open older projects in the IDE, Android Studio frequently gives me an Alert "**To take advantage of all the latest features...we strongly recommend that you update the Android Gradle plugin to version x.x.x and Gradle to version x.x**" (see screenshot below).

Once I click **Update**, I must **sync the project with Gradle Files** ([which takes forever for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850112/android-studio-2-3-1-editing-build-gradle-file-causes-ide-to-freeze-for-20-sec)).  I open 15 - 20 old projects on an average day, and the message gets tedious.

[image: Android Gradle Plugin Update Recommended ScreenShot]

Comment: Um, write a script to update your projects. I wrote mine in ~60 lines of Ruby.

Comment: a script. of course! dunno why I didn't think of that. thanks!

Comment: btw @CommonsWare, I'm a big fan. Love your books and talks at conferences as well as all the answers you provide on StackOverflow. Keep up the great work :)

Comment: One of the handy things about text-based configuration files is the ability to beat 'em into submission with scripts when needed. :-) And thanks for the kind words!

Comment: If you do actually decide to go with automatic version updates, take care to test everything after updating the project. Who knows, maybe the project you just opened has a dependency that uses some obscure internal API of the build system, that might get removed in the newer version, or whatever.
One of the more recent examples I've encountered: Kotlin's annotation processor failed me on the newer version.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15359

Comment: @CommonsWare care to share said script?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't needed that script in years, and I don't have it handy anymore. It also wasn't exactly bulletproof -- it was adequate for my needs and my projects, nothing more.