# Android Studio 2.3.3 stuck on Gradle Build Running

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Using android studio 2.3.3 I've stuck on `Gradle Build Running`.
I don't have any idea and loss my mind to figure it out what happened with my project. Recently we want to compile `Zoom Login Application Sample` and following carefully from this [link](https://dev.zoomlogin.com/zoomsdk/#/android-guide).

Here are Android Studio Version :

```
Android Studio 2.3.3
Build #AI-162.4069837, built on June 6, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_31-b13 x86
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```

On event log, Grade seems working hard to finish this task

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
```

I've tried to

1. Set `Global Gradle Setting` to `Offline Work` by followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35859572/1533670)
2. Isn't using google play service like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33978477/1533670) suggest.
3. Not using proxy
4. Add `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and `org.gradle.parallel=true` on `gradle.properties` project
5. On `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\gradle.properties` add this line `org.gradle.daemon=true` and `org.gradle.parallel=true`

Every solution I tried but no one work well. This is silly and ridiculous, the build phase cannot be completed even I leave that for one night.

Here is `project build.gradle` :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.facialnetwork.com/maven2'
            credentials {
                username '***'
                password '***'
            }
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
        }

        // Reference local .aar file if it doesn't exist in maven
        flatDir{ dirs '../../../' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and here `module build.gradle`

```
buildscript {

}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    if (project.hasProperty("zoom_keystore")) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile file(zoom_keystore)
                storePassword zoom_keystore_password
                keyAlias zoom_key_alias
                keyPassword zoom_key_password
            }
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.facetec.zoom.sampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField("String", "ZOOM_APP_TOKEN", System.getProperty("zoom_app_token", "\"\""))
        resConfigs "en"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            if (signingConfigs.hasProperty('release')) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.facetec:zoom-authentication:5.1.1@aar'
    compile project(':zoom-authentication-5.1.1')
}
```

after trying to build from gradlew command line `gradlew -d assembleDebug`,
I got this log, maybe can help identify my problem :

```
09:08:19.942 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock
acquired.
09:08:19.942 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Relea
sing lock on daemon addresses registry.
> Building 62% > :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
```

Its stuck on task `:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac`

I've tried to delete caches on `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\caches` and still hang on `:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac` process

I cannot figure it out. Any Idea? What I miss out?
Thanks.

Comment: Try to build your project from the commandline. If it also hangs, add `-d` to see exactly what's going on where it is probably hanging. If you cannot interpret it yourself, you might post the result for helpers to review.

Comment: @Vampire Have tried to build from command line. I've updated my question. Seems it stuck on process `:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac`. Any idea?

Comment: Try deleting `<root project>/.gradle`. But I doubt it will help. No other ideas, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

CTRL + SHIFT + ESC -> Process -> Kill **java.exe** -> Rebuild

Answer (score 1):

I also face this problem.

and i m really tired because i continuously 3 days find this solution.

then i show in gradle console. in which it show error: **C:\Users\khimsuriya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\29.0.3-> "aapt" does not start.**

so i change ***"build tool version" to 26.0.3 and the error was finished.***

so you try change "build tool version" in your build.gradle(app level). it continue still you find perfect "**strong text**build tool version"

it is 100% work.

My number .9725414329

Comment: Changing the build tools to 26.0.0 solved my problem with "Cannot Parse Version 52 Byte Code" Problem, which was the reason I tried to update everything else. It's really about the build tools; in the aftermath it makes sense.