# Gradle build takes too much time to build with jack enabled

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using lambda expressions in code for which to support i have added following in the module gradle :

```
 jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }

  compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
```

But build is taking too much time , more than 10 mins , i tried searching other posts , found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42291280/3820753) mentioning problems using jack .

So i just wanted to know if anyone's using jackOptions and is able to run/build the project smoothly .

TIA .

Comment: Jack is discontinued with Android Studio 3.0. You might consider switching to it earlier (it is at RC2 right now), so you can use the Java 8 features that Jack supported without Jack.

Comment: but i am using 2.3.3

Comment: As I said, you might consider switching to Android Studio 3.0, if not now, when it is released in final form (which should be soon). In the meantime, hold off on anything that requires Jack, if it takes too long for you to build.

Comment: right , worked with 3.0 , thanks .