# Android studio gradle never builds

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Gradle takes too long to build on android studio on my new pc.
It has never built on this pc.
It doesn't show any error, in "event log".
just that:

- Gradle sync started
- Gradle sync completed
- Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSource, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSource, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependecies]

StatusBar: Gradle Build Running

it never ends

I tried that:

Settings/../Gradle :   Work offline (checked)

---

System OS and  cfg:

os: windows 10
System type: 64 bit
cpu:  intel i7 6900k
ram: 128 GB

---

what's wrong? why gradle doesn't build?
Do I miss anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio gradle takes too long to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/android-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build)

Comment: @ShibinRajuMathew sorry, title edited. It never builds and never shows any error

Comment: What is the longest you have waited? Sometimes it takes awhile to build. Also, how are you creating you build? Are you doing it via the command-line or running the code from the top tool bar? Have you tried cleaning and then rebuilding?

Comment: may be your gradle is downloading gradle.zip file from internet and trying to sync after that which is taking time.

Comment: not sure what your problem , but you can try following link to speed up your gradle build.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/android-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai  more than 3 hours I waited.  when I open a new project it should build gradle first that never builds,  and I can't clean project until build finished.

Comment: @vikaskumar my internet connection is disabled, how can I check it?

Comment: @vikaskumar I don't have gradle build speed problem, my problem is gradle build, it doesn't finish building, check out my system configuration at the end of my question, I think it's enough to build a gradle, but it has never done :(

Comment: first make sure you have a working internet connection with good speed as gradle zip file is around 80 to 90 mb and then make sure you have disabled offline working . This should work fine.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file?

Comment: @vikaskumar Let's make a try, tnx

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai I'm using stack exchange (mobile app). I can't send long texts and codes

Comment: check if you need vpn or sth like that , using some services of google is not allowed in your country

Comment: @tahaDev it was the problem, I needed a good internet speed and vpn. Thanks a lot for taking time.

Comment: @Mr.Farshad , Welcome , Don't forget to upvote if it was the accepted answer Happy Coding ... (;