# My application is in the process of being installed for a long time

Tags: android

it is android 6.0.
release version：The installation time is too long（10-15 minutes） apk size:8M.
debug version: normal.

What should I do? thanks.

Comment: unlock the smartphone...

Comment: Hello, it's open

Comment: Do you mean Gradle build is taking too much time ? if so see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/android-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build

Comment: @RohitSingh That's not the case，build the APK,It takes too long to install on a smartphone.