# How to fix Android app crashing that uses Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My problem is quite a troublesome one, i made an app on Android Studio that has a TextView that displays the Firebase registration token upon launch (I'm still new to Firebase and Android Studio, i'm experimenting), i've been building APK files of my app to test it on my phone since Android Studio doesn't detect my phone when it's hooked to my laptop for some reason and i can't use emulation because my laptop is old (i think it doesn't support virtualization), so whenever i try to launch my app on my phone i get the equivalent of MyApp stopped working in French and i don't know how to view the crash log files.

tl;dr i wanna know what's causing my app to crash

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView= findViewById(R.id.textViewToken);
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                      if(task.isSuccessful()){
                          String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                          textView.setText("Token : " + token);
                        }
                        else
                      {
                          textView.setText("Token Not Generated");
                      }
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

Edit: i managed to run my app on my phone through Android Studio by downloading the right drivers, i checked the logcat when i ran it and i got this:

```
03-31 18:55:45.069 8855-8855/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie, PID: 8855
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie/com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:219)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Edit 2:
I added the following line of code referred by user [Riley Manda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6129553/rileymanda):

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

in `onCreate()` method and i get this error now:

**log trace:**

```
03-31 19:10:19.203 11562-11562/com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie, PID: 11562
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie/com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:219)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Edit 3: I'm making another thread about this problem since it seems like the thread has drifted away from its original purpose, thanks everyone for answering.

Comment: Did you enable the developer settings on your phone? Did you install appropriate drivers (if on Windows)? You may also need to switch to "USB for file access" or similar for your phone to be recognized. It's impossible to give any feedback without seeing code or errors

Comment: yes i have it on the equivalent of media file transfer in French for USB access which is obviously the best choice, i enabled developer settings and USB debugging but Android Studio still doesn't detect, i'll check for drivers @derpirscher

Comment: PLease past your error messgae  your code seem fine

Comment: @amosgodwin read the question... he said he can't connect the phone and does not have log trace

Comment: @Sam. He said He gets the equivalent of my apps not working in french

Comment: @amosgodwin Care to explain this _i've been building APK files of my app to test it on my phone since Android Studio doesn't detect my phone when it's hooked to my laptop for some reason and i can't use emulation because my laptop is old_

Comment: @amosgodwin Yes my app crashes whenever i launch it on my phone and i have no access to the log trace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Updated question with log trace

Answer (score 1):

Connect your app to Crashlytics,this way you will receive crash emails that will lead you to the exact issue thats causing your app to crash.

[image]

Follow the instructions on firebase to setup crashlytics for your app in Android Studio.And each time your app crashes, you will receive an email from Crashlytics:

[image]

This way, each time your app crashes from your physical devices notification email from Crashlytics is automatically sent to your email indicating the exact line of code/issue that's causing your app to crash.

Based on your crashLog:

You have to initialise firebase in your activity:
Add this to your activity:

```
 FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

In your onCreate:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

Comment: Yes you're right, i installed the drivers now though and will soon have the log trace and will update my post as soon as it's done building (been doing so for 15 minutes)

Comment: Great.If my answer was helpful, please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: In Addition,you can always enable "offline work"in your Android studio to speed up the build speeds.Check out this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/android-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build link :for details on how to enable "offline work"

Comment: You're answer was helpful, thanks, but it wasn't the correct answer, i updated my question with the log trace though.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);`just after `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);`  or before you make any connections to firebase

Also for your device not showing in android studio

- first enable developers Options On your Phone    https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-get-developer-options-on-android/
- Enable Usb Debugging in the developers Options of your Phone settings
- Secondly install an adb driver on your System  and try reconnecting your device
- Accept the prompt on your phone that asks if you want to trust your system and it should work

Comment: Thanks amos for your answer, i already added FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this); in my onCreate() method just after setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
as for my device connection i already solved that by downloading the appropriate drivers, thanks!