# Gradle build running a long time in task "processDebugResources"

Tags: android, gradle

My android project runs Gradle build running in about 7 min every time.

And the "Task :launcher:processDebugResources" takes 5 min.

What did it do?

I read and try all the answer in
[Android Studio gradle takes too long to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/android-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build)
But no use, sadly.

And how to fix it please?

The full log:

> Task :launcher:bundleDebugResources
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-osx Daemon #0 Failed to shutdown within timeout
> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-osx Daemon #0: Failed to shut down within 30 seconds. Forcing shutdown
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.stopProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:224)
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.shutDown(Aapt2Daemon.kt:148)
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.handleError(Aapt2Daemon.kt:183)
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.handleError$default(Aapt2Daemon.kt:168)
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.link(Aapt2Daemon.kt:128)
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:175)

Comment: many reason are there. Slow internet if it's online and other lib version management. Module management

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the reason.
If AS takes a long the in the task "processDebugResources",it means you have too many resources to process in appt task.

Check you build.gradle, find the "aaptOptions".

And my code likes:

```
aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['a','b','c','d','e']
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }
```

noCompress = ['a','b','c','d','e'] just for an example.

Check the noCompress Array. If you have too many item in Array,try to remove some items.And it will be better.

I didn't find anything wrong after I deleted them. Maybe you will,please tell us how to do better.