# Android Studio Gradle sync and build taking too much time

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, build.gradle

I have been working on a project at my office and in weekends I took the laptop to work from home. At office we're working behind proxy (1-2 minutes build time), but at home I am not behind proxy. I have disabled proxy from windows settings and I have a stable internet connection.

***Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1***

Checked connection from Settings-> Appearance and behavior -> System settings -> HTTP Proxy -> check connection. I have followed literally all suggestions from the post below. Build not happening and it's taking hours. No result.

[Android Studio gradle takes too long to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/android-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build?rq=4)

[image]

Stuck with this issue.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: As you can see on the left side Android Studio is trying to download something. May be you have network problems or the used repository for downloading has a problem. I would restart your system to reset everything. make sure internet access and access to all used repos works without problems.

Comment: @Robert I had a global .gradle file configured, that created the issue. Please see the answer below. Anyways TYSM.

Answer (score 0):

***Solved..***

I was working with multiple Android Studio IDEs and there was a globally configured .gradle file at C:\Users\FM.gradle. This override the ***Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1*** configurations.

[image]

Happy Coding.