# Android build gradle is too slow (Dependency Resolution)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've been working with Android Studio (my current version 1.5) for 2 years. Everything was OK, but when I downloaded Canary (2.1 p5), everything went wrong. Every time I want to create a new project or open a project or sync or import a new lib or dependency, gradle is taking too long to build — **nearly 20 min**.

I did not do anything, I just downloaded the Canary version and ran it.

**Symptoms :**

1. It happened when I connected to Internet
2. The first delay is on *Gradle: Resolve dependencies ':app:_debugCompile'*
3. ...
4. After 25 min building almost done

**Note**:
*When I disconnect my Internet, gradle will finish as fast as possible*

---

**I tried to fix this by these ways**:

1. I changed the gradle to offline work (it worked but I don't want this way, because I want to import libs or dependencies)
2. I've created a new file (file name is `gradle.properties`) in `C:\Users\username\.gradle` then wrote these lines into it

   ```
   org.gradle.parallel=true
   org.gradle.daemon=true
   ```
3. I removed that version then installed my old version which worked OK but the problem was still there :(
4. Disable / Enable firewall
5. Disable / Enable AntiVirus (Nod32)
6. Reinstall Windows OS (8.1)
7. I've downloaded all versions (1.0.0, ..., 1.5.1, 2.0.0, 2.1)
8. I've used a proxy

---

**System info**:

- CPU: Intel Core i5
- Ram: 6.00 GB
- OS: Windows 8.1 64 bit

---

**build.gradle(Project:appName)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle.build(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

**Gradle report after building**

```
Dependencies                  Duration
All dependencies              14m3.43s
:app:_releaseCompile          3m30.96s
:app:_debugCompile            3m30.73s
:app:_debugApk                3m30.69s
:app:_releaseApk              3m30.62s
:classpath                    0.428s
:app:_debugAndroidTestCompile 0.001s
:app:_debugAndroidTestApk     0s
:app:_debugUnitTestApk        0s
:app:_debugUnitTestCompile    0s
:app:_releaseUnitTestApk      0s
:app:_releaseUnitTestCompile  0s
:app:releaseWearApp           0s
:app:wearApp                  0s
```

**After installing android studio 2.0 stable version**

- 7:23:47 PM Gradle sync started ====>
  8:13:21 PM Gradle sync completed

Comment: The fully released Android Studio 2.0 is available now, so no need to use a canary version.  With that, you should also update your android gradle plugin version to 2.0.0 (not 1.5.0).

Comment: Did not work for me .

Comment: Ok , I got it , but what can I do ?
What is the solution to pass this problem?

Comment: where is that .gradle file in linux?

Comment: Related: you can also enable offline mode for Gradle in Android Studio: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22564785/245966

Answer (score 87, accepted):

### The problem is solved !

After 2 days searching , I got the solution , so I would like to share with all people who may have the same problem. The problem is `gradle`can not connect to center repository in some country. When you create a new project or import , your center repository is `jcenter()` by default and whenever you want to build or sync or add new external dependency, `gradle` is going to connect to https://bintray.com/ but it can not and the building process is going to wait till connect to `jcenter()`, so this process might take long time ( +30 min ) , even you can not add new dependency .

**Solution :**

1. Make sure you have latest stable version ( current 2.0.0 )
2. Make sure your gradle version is 2.0.0 in build.gradle (`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'`)
3. Final step and most important one is change your **jcenter()** to **mavenCentral()**

So you can easily add new dependency and sync project under 3sec !

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Have Fun

Comment: but i still use jcenter(). i have not problem

Comment: In my experience step1 and step2 are not necessary.

Comment: It works...better than it was...now it builds lesser than 30secs.

Comment: Funny jcenter doesn't connect even with vpn and proxy server. I'm not sure if they blocking some countries or it's the ISPs. Eyval dada

Comment: Anytime bro  ...
@Pedram

Comment: But I still have this problem when creating new project! Is there any solution to change that jcenter even in start up? zemnan dadash namoosan damet garm :D

Comment: beside creating new project I have problem with building project either even though after do the changes and in my case Gradle take a long time on `app:_debugUnitTestCompile` my Gradle version is 2.2.3

Comment: `jcenter` gives you more libraries than `mavenCentral`. It's a **superset**

Comment: Could not find com.novoda:bintray-release:0.8.0. **after** change jcenter() to mavenCentral()

Comment: Nowadays , all dependencies have been found in jcenter . mavenCentral() is not a common repo . Try to use jcenter() but first make sure you are using VPN and fast Internet connection .
@ImanMarashi

Comment: This gives  Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.

Answer (score 6):

You could optimize the gradle build process ...

Try to put the gradle on offline mode forcing to build without any connection to external repositories, like this:

[image]
[image]

This helped me a lot, because in my work, all connections are behind a proxy and it increase the build time.

If this is not enough for you, take a time testing the options on the Gradle > Experimental ... Some options may improve you performance:

[image]

**Note**: In newer version of Android studio, `View->Tool Windows->Gradle->Toggle button of online/offline`

Answer (score 3):

Once the initial build has completed try enabling offline Mode from the gradle settings. So that every consecutive builds will not start resolving dependencies, instead it gets from the cache. If you add a new dependency it will prompt you to disable offline mode and rebuild it. [image: image of the gradle preview]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Mehdi Jahed Manesh answer above.

Increase the amount of memory allocated to the Gradle Daemon VM by 1 Gb, to a minimum of 2 Gb, using the `org.gradle.jvmargs` property like this:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
```

Answer (score 2):

Like [Ismail Iqbal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46169065/4158282) said, put gradle under offline mode works for me.

1. If you're using android studio, follow [Fabio Filho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48650843/4158282)
2. If you're using command line like me, you can try

```
gradlew assembleReleaseStaging(your task name) --offline
```

Answer (score 1):

**For those who use repositories that require authentication**, this issue may be solved by configuring gradle to use only a single auth scheme:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username INTERNAL_REPO_USERNAME
            password INTERNAL_REPO_PASSWORD
        }
        // here comes the important part
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
        url INTERNAL_REPO_URL
    }
}
```

It turned out that upon authenticating against repositories, gradle attempts authentication using all kind of schemes. The above config makes gradle only use basic auth. [Here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.authentication.Authentication.html) is the full list of available schemes.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this story. It might not related to gradle but it can speed up your build without too much changes:

`https://android.jlelse.eu/is-your-android-studio-always-slow-heres-how-to-speed-up-immediately-326ef9238024`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved it by installing a new version of the Java JDK.
After installing the new JDK, open AS, go to File→Project Structure→SDK Location, and change JDK location to that of the new version of the Java JDK. Then you will be asked for firewall permission; check Public and apply. Let it resolve gradle.

Answer (score 0):

stop the gradle download and click file -> "Sync project with Gradle Files"

Answer (score 0):

The crazy way is using WARP 1.1.1.1. I already wasted my half day waiting for 10 MB downloaded :(.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen another issue. The solution might help someone

Recently i have set http_proxy and https_proxy under system environment variables. I had to remove both of them and then set the proxy in studio settings.

Answer (score -3):

change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'`
to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

and
change `buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"`
to

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

and use android studio 2.0 stable version.
let me know you want more details or this solution did not work to you.

Comment: Sure , let me test it .

Comment: I`ve downloaded 2.0 stable version and those steps , but nothing has not changed yet.